# Como posso usar corretamente um objeto PDO para uma consulta seleção

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

eu segui as recomendações da php.net, para fazer um select em um determinado banco de dados utilizando o PDO, no entanto eu não sei se estou fazendo da maneira certa, gostaria de saber se vocês podem me ajudar

```
$duosig = "SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019";
$stm = $lokos->query($duosig);
$stm->execute();
echo $NOMCLI;
```

Comment: no caso ali $nomcli, seria $row['NOMCLI'];

Answer (score 2):

Você recebe os dados do *statement*, através do método [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

No blog [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/), tem um artigo [Introdução ao PHP PDO](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-php-pdo/24973#ixzz3fJEB7def), que seria uma boa leitura.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, email) VALUES(?, ?)"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1, "Nome da Pessoa");  // Altera o primeiro "?" da query para "Nome da Pessoa"
$stmt->bindParam(2, "email@email.com");  // Altera o segundo "?" da query para "email@email.com"
$stmt->execute(); // Executa a query

$rs = $con->query("SELEC idpessoa, nome, email FROM pessoa"); // Busca os dados no banco
while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){ // Lê uma linha de cada vez
   echo $row->idpessoa . "<br />"; 
   echo $row->nome . "<br />"; 
   echo $row->email . "<br />"; 
}
```

Aplicando os conhecimentos no seu caso:

```
$duosig = "SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019"; // SQL
$rs = $lokos->query($duosig); // Executa a query
$row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) // Recebe uma linha de dados
echo $row->NOMCLI; // Imprime um dados
```

Para receber várias linhas de dados coloque a expressão *fetch* em um *loop*

```
while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
  // Use os dados $row->NOMECOLUNA
}
```

Caso vá aplicar uma clausura *where*, sempre use o [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT NOMCLI FROM SINAF019 WHERE ID = ?"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1, 5, PDO::PARAM_INT); // Altera o primeiro "?" para "5"
$stmt->execute(); // Executa o statement
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) // Recebe uma linha de dados
echo $row->NOMCLI; // Imprime um dados
```